# freenas - using other partitions

Tags: file-sharing, freenas

I am repurposing my old dell with a 650gig HDD on it.  I installed freenas and everything installed fairly easily.  I setup a shortcut to the freenas but it says I only have 5MB available.  How do I get the other 649.5gigs to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.  When I had 5mb I was mounting to the wrong partition (1).  When I redid the mounting I did it to partition 2 and now I have 632 gigs!